# pass props from parent to child (modal)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

[image]

[image]

I am a new in React and I will explain my problem in detail:

At first I have a Todo project, and within this project I have several interfaces.

The project is an interface that displays all the lists, and each list contains the list title and a group of tasks, and also contains a button to create a task. Also, when the “Create new task” button is pressed, a modal is opened to enter the data for the task that will be created.

For this scenario I have three interfaces:

Lists -
SingleList -
Task Modal

And I called the components together in this way:

lists --> singleList --> taskModal

Where inside the Lists I called a SingleList and inside the SingleList I called a TaskModal.

Lists is the parent who fetches the data from the api and then passes the data to the "singleList" component.

To create a task, you must pass three variables:

```
todoListId - title - content
```

My problem is that I couldn't pass the "todoListId" from the "singleList" to the "taskModal".

This is the father class, in which "GetAllListsAction" was called, and this action fetches data from the backend.

lists.tsx:

```
const Lists: React.FC<{
  TodoListList: any;
  GetAllListsAction: Function;
}> = ({ GetAllListsAction, TodoListList }) => {
  const classes = useStyle();
  useEffect(() => {
    // call action to fetch lists
    GetAllListsAction();
    console.log("TodoListList: ", TodoListList);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />

      <Grid className={classes.grid}>
        <Grid
          container
          className={classes.addButton}
          item
          direction="row-reverse"
        >
          <ListModal />
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item lg={12} direction="row" spacing={1}>
          {Array.isArray(TodoListList) &&
            TodoListList?.map((l: ListItem, index: number) => (
              <Grid key={index} item lg={3} sm={6} xs={12}>
                <SingleList
                  // todoListId={l.todoListId}
                  id={l.id}
                  title={l.title || ""}
                  todos={l.todos}
                />
              </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      ...Actions,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
  console.log("state: ", state.todoList?.state);
  return {
    TodoListList: state.todoList?.state || [],
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Lists);
```

Through this component, the component "TaskModal" was called.

singleList.tsx:

```
interface in_SingleList {
  id?: number;
  title: string;
  todos?: Todo[];
}

const SingleList: React.FC<in_SingleList> = (data: in_SingleList) => {
  console.log("data inside single list: ", data);
  const classes = useStyle();

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.root}>
      {/* 1 */}
      <Grid item>
        <Grid container>
          {/* 1-1 */}
          <Grid item>
            <Card elevation={4} className={classes.card}>
              <Grid item>
                <Grid container>
                  <CardHeader
                    classes={{
                      title: classes.headerTitle,
                    }}
                    title={data.title}
                  ></CardHeader>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              {/* 1-1-1 */}
              <Grid item>
                <Grid container>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Grid container direction="column" spacing={3}>
                      {/* 1-1-1-1 */}
                      {data.todos?.map((t: Todo, index: number) => (
                        <Grid item key={index}>
                          <CardTodo title={t.title || ""} />
                        </Grid>
                      ))}
                    </Grid>
                  </CardContent>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>

              {/* 1-1-2 */}
              <Grid item className={classes.button}>
                <TaskModal />
              </Grid>
            </Card>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default SingleList;
```

This component is the modal for creating a task.

TaskModal.tsx:

```
interface in_TaskModal {
  todoListId?: number;
}

interface todoProps {
  todocard: Object;
  CreateCardAction: Function;
}

type Props = in_TaskModal & todoProps;

const TaskModal: React.FC<Props> = ({
  CreateCardAction,
  todocard,
  todoListId,
}) => {
  console.log("todocard: ", todocard);
  const classes = useStyle();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState("");

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    CreateCardAction(title, content, todoListId);
    handleClose();
    console.log("title inside list modal: ", title);
  };

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="flex-start"
        alignItems="flex-end"
      >
        <Grid item>
          <Grid
            container
            direction="row"
            justifyContent="flex-start"
            alignItems="flex-end"
          >
            <Button
              onClick={handleClickOpen}
              className={classes.createTaskbutton}
              startIcon={<AddIcon style={{ fontSize: 17 }} />}
            >
              Create new task
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        container
        lg={12}
        xs={12}
        justifyContent="center"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        <Dialog
          classes={{ root: classes.root }}
          // className={classes.root}
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
        >
          <Grid container direction="column">
            <Grid item>
              <Grid container direction="column">
                <Grid item>
                  <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">
                    <Grid container direction="column">
                      <Grid item>
                        <Grid container direction="row">
                          <Grid item>
                            <SubtitlesIcon className={classes.icon} />
                          </Grid>

                          <Grid item>
                            <Typography className={classes.text}>
                              Task Title
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item>
                        <TextField
                          className={classes.titleField}
                          id="standard-basic"
                          value={title}
                          onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </DialogTitle>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>{/* llll */}</Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText>
                  <Grid container direction="row">
                    <Grid item>
                      <NotesIcon className={classes.icon} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                      <Typography className={classes.text}>
                        Description
                      </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </DialogContentText>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  style={{ textAlign: "left" }}
                  multiline
                  rows={2}
                  className={classes.titleField}
                  value={content}
                  onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
                />
              </DialogContent>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              item
              container
              justifyContent="flex-start"
              alignItems="flex-end"
            >
              <DialogActions>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  className={classes.button}
                  onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                  Create Task
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Dialog>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: any) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      ...Actions,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
  console.log("todo card: ", state);
  return {
    todocard: state,
  };
}

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export default connector(TaskModal);
```

The form of the response when all the lists are returned via the api:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Whwtever",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-06T05:44:48.019Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-06T05:44:48.019Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "todos": [
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "title": "awesome day",
                    "content": "whatever",
                    "status": "TODO",
                    "todoListId": 1,
                    "createdAt": "2021-12-06T20:18:34.379Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2021-12-06T20:18:34.379Z",
                    "deletedAt": null,
                    "version": 0
                }
            
    ],
    "count": 80,
    "total": 80,
    "page": 1,
    "pageCount": 1
}
```

body for createTask:

```
{
    "title": "awesome day",
    "content": "whatever",
    "todoListId": 3
}
```

response for createTask:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 6,
        "title": "awesome day",
        "content": "whatever",
        "status": "TODO",
        "todoListId": 3,
        "createdAt": "2021-12-30T17:28:31.229Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-12-30T17:28:31.229Z",
        "deletedAt": null,
        "version": 0,
        "todoList": {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "vqw",
            "createdAt": "2021-12-15T12:36:22.610Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-12-15T12:36:22.610Z",
            "deletedAt": null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal-Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: In the code posted you don't pass any properties to `<TaskModal>`. The `id` is avaliable from its parent properites as `data.id`, `todocard` property for `TaskModal` seems to be not used in this component other than in `console.log`, so I wonder if you need it at all. And the `CreateCardAction` I don't see defined anywhere.

Comment: i use CreateCardAction inside TaskModal.

Comment: when i pass todolist={data.id} to taskModal child i get error

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to handle it with routing, when you click on "create new task" button simply push "todoListId" to current route history and trigger route changing in modal for open modal.You can access "todoListId" from current route now.

Comment: can you edit my code please? @enayatfard